# How to filter between two databases?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have two databases:

```
   DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'new',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'old': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'old',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

and model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    data = some other data
```

Old database contains some removed entries and some of the new database.How to filter entries from new database that there are no entries from the old database?

Comment: It's not currently supported, unless you "fake" it in certain cases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases

Answer (score 1):

I made this:

```
f1 = MyModel.objects.using('old').all()

pids = [p.id for p in f1]

f2 = MyModel.objects.exclude(id__in=pids).filter()
```

But I don't know if it is good.